# How to execute selenium tests in GUI mode in Azure VM instance in which jenkins is installed

Tags: linux, azure, selenium, jenkins, putty

I have on VM with Jenkins installed hosted in Azure which is Linux operating system.I want to execute the selenium scripts in that VM through Jenkins.I am able to execute the tests in headless mode.But the problem here is I need to run the tests in GUI mode.Is there any workaround to run the automation scripts in GUI mode.Below are the things I have tried to run in GUI mode.

1. Installed chrome browser through putty and set the chrome binary path.
2. Tried to access VM through xrdp.

But I am not able to execute in GUI mode.Any help will be much appreciated.

Chrome version : 65

Below is the error log :

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 60.15 seconds
>   Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T18:33:54.468Z'

Comment: You need to provide with some logs or something

Comment: Your setup doesn't seem to have a display. Xvfb is the most common option for linux.

Comment: i have installed xvfb and setting the display also

Comment: @SaiPawan You could check this [blog](http://stgconsulting.com/running-automated-selenium-tests-from-jenkins-on-linux/), but please let me know what error or what step you have question?

Comment: @Shengbao Shui yes i have done the same things but my VM is Azure VM and i am getting error as "chrome exited abruptly"

Comment: @SaiPawan Could you show some error log as a screenshot?

Comment: Added error log

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092

Comment: Can you update the question with the version of `Chrome` browser you are using?

Answer (score 1):

I found this [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurearmtools/blob/master/.azure-pipelines/linux/test-linux.yml) on Azure Pipelines repo. I only managed to get it working after I copied this piece of code and the file [xvfb.init](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurearmtools/blob/master/.azure-pipelines/linux/xvfb.init).

```
steps:
- script: |
    sudo cp .azure-pipelines/linux/xvfb.init /etc/init.d/xvfb
    sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/xvfb
    sudo update-rc.d xvfb defaults
    sudo service xvfb start
  displayName: 'Start X Virtual Frame Buffer'

- script: |
    export DISPLAY=:10
    gulp test
  displayName: 'Test'
```